# Use SQL REGEXP to ignore number and get only String and '/'

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL table with a column of type `varchar(255)` which holds the data in the following formats:

```
400 mg
50/12,5 mg/ml
20 mikrog
500 mg/400 IU
60 mikrog/15 mikrog
```

I need to ignore the number and only extract the string(s), in some cases, including `/`, so that the data from above looks like this:

```
mg
mg/ml
mikrog
mg/IU
mikrog/mikrog
```

I tried using `REGEXP` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '[a-z]') FROM db.table;
```

But, that just gives me a bunch of letters, like this

```
m
I
U
a
g
k
```

Is there any way to use `REGEXP` to extract String of any length, as in my case, the String that needs extracting is of varying length, for example, in case of `mg`, it's `2`, in case of `mikrog`, it's `6`. Also, in some cases, I need to include the character `/`.

Comment: seems your Database's version is 8+,isn't it?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes

Comment: Parse your data in your application, _not_ in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may remove the numbers to get what you need:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(column, ' *[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?(/[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?)? *', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rcPnVM/1).

**Details**

- `*` - 0+ spaces
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `([.,][0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of a comma or period followed with 1+ digits
- `(/[0-9]+([.,][0-9]+)?)?` - an optional sequence of a `/` and then 1+ digits followed optionally with `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
- `*` - 0+ spaces

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regexp

Try to use `[a-z]*` to get only all letters,
or `[a-z]*\/[a-z]*` to get even the slash.

Take a look [here](https://regex101.com/) and test some examples

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `instr()` and `substring()`

```
select substring(col, instr(col, ' '))
from your_table
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f7f42/1)