# regexp match for a number between 2 patterns

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to add a regexp in my SQL query to find a specific number in a string.

The parameters of this search should be that :

- Number at the beginning of the string
- Number at the end of the string
- Number between + or | characters.
  For example finding if the string 3+26|2+12 contains the number 2

I was able to write a regexp that is working fine for PHP : 
`(?<=^|\+|\|)(2)(?=\||\+|$)`
But I discovered that MySQL doesn't support this kind of regexp.

Any help to convert it to a MySQL compatible regex ?

Thank you.

Comment: I was guided by this answer previously https://stackoverflow.com/a/57250671/10910692 ..

Comment: MySQL v8+ supports this syntax. Which version do you have? If you need to just return all records matching this kind of pattern use `(^|[+|])2([|+]|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in MySQL v8+, you may use lookarounds and the

```
(?<=^|[+|])2(?=[|+]|$)
```

is valid with the ICU regex library.

However, you may simply use alternations inside groups. This pattern will work in older MySQL, too:

```
(^|[+|])2([|+]|$)
```

The pattern will return all records containing texts matching

- `(^|[+|])`  - start of record, `+` or `|`
- `2` - `2` char
- `([|+]|$)`  - end of record, `+` or `|`

Comment: Thanks for the explanations this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out of the box...

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, 
   REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '+', ','), '|', ',')) )
```

With REGEXP_REPLACE(), it can be written simpler:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, 
   REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[+|]', ',') )
```